# React - Import App from './App.jsx'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jsx, babeljs

I am trying to learn Node and React and I ran into an interesting problem where - in the import statement like below, I need to explicitly type the file format (.jsx) otherwise, the compiler borks up and complains that it cannot find App.js file.

```
            import App from './App.jsx';
```

Note - App is a jsx file and saved as App.jsx. I used create-react-app for boilerplate code.

Comment: if you are using webpack add edit the config and add the extension `.jsx` to allowed file extensions

Answer (score 2):

Also, I found some more information on GitHub on the lines of "*The distinction between .js and .jsx files was useful before Babel, but it’s not that useful anymore.*"

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/87

So, it looks like a non-issue as long as save it as .js and I have babel to compile ES6.. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Here your assumption is incorrect.

If I am right then you are assuming that if your file is `.jsx`, then you don't need to specify the file extension in the import statement to import `.jsx` file.

But its the other way round.

If you don't specify the extension of the file then compiler assumes that it is a `.js` file. So, there is nothing wrong with the behavior that you are seeing.

**OR**

If you don't want to include extensions in the import statement then just create `.js` files. Compiler will automatically detect the `jsx` written inside it. This is the easiest way to fool import statement.

Answer (score 0):

Any javascript react snippets will not show up in a plain .js file only a .jsx file

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that closing the running project on Browser
(ctrl + c / command + c on terminal to finish running project) and do
'yarn start' or 'npm start' again. then it would work!
React sometimes shows errors when you add new files like jsx, js, etc..
and I also had the same problem with you.
(I changed App.js to App.jsx and webppack error was occured).
In these case re-starting project would be the solution!

finally you don't need to specify file extension (like the other answers suggestion).